# how to find closure in chrome debugger for anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

while debugging, Where do I find  closure  in the case of anonymous functions?

In the case of non-anonymous function, it seems to appear under "functional scope". For eg:

```
    function outer(x){
    var temp = 0;
    return function inner(){
        alert(++x);
    };
    }
    var out = outer(3);
    out();
    debugger;
    out = outer(5);
    out();
```

In this case, I can see[closure_in_functionalscope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnJDW.jpg) in watch expression of "out".

However, when I use anonymous function as shown below:

```
    function outer(x){
    var temp = 0;
    return function (){
        alert(++x);
    };
    }
    outer(3)();
    debugger;
    outer(5)();
```

In this case, I don't see [anonymous function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh2ms.jpg) as closure in watch expression.  Which object stores the closure in the case of anonymous function?

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with the inner function being named or not.

In the first screenshot you're inspecting the `out` variable, which references a function returned but `outer`. That function has `x` in its closure scope.

In the second screenshot you're inspecting the `outer` variable, which references a named global function. In that code snippet you don't have any variable to reference the result or `outer(3)`. If you assign that to a variable just like you do in the first example `var out = outer(3)` and put a breakpoint after that assignment, you'll be able to see `out`'s closure scope. Alternatively, you can inspect that by adding a "watch expression" of `outer(3)` in the debugger without the need to modify your code.